# Making an API request inside a DLL in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I am currently making a weather app in Visual Basic that makes a API call to  openweathermap.org to obtain current weather.  When I tested this as a Windows Forms application it worked great, but when I incorporated it into DLL there was an error saying object reference not set to instance of an object the code is as follows:

```
    Dim request as httpwebrequest= net.Webrequest.create("api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=delhi,in&mode=xml&appid=")
    Dim response as net.webresponse=request.getresponse()
    Dim stream as IO. Stream=response.getresponsestream()
    Dim xmldoc as new xmldocument
    Xmldoc.Load(stream)
```

The error comes in the line

```
Xmldoc.Load(stream)
```

Where it says object reference not set to instance of an object. The same statement was working perfect in a Windows Forms application.

Comment: Have you tried lower case xmldoc?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: whether it's "in a DLL" as you put it (which just means it got compiled into a class library file), or not, won't matter. The problem is you're trying to access an object which isn't defined or instantiated. That can happen in any code, in any context

Comment: I am sorry halter to address my question in such manner

Comment: I will take care from next time